# The begining of Lookers quest

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Okay so I forgot where the looker tells you to go after you step out into Lumiose City so all I remember is looker bridge but I don't know where that is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.serebii.net/xy/looker.shtml

Comment: You can always check your HoloCaster to re-read messages.

Answer (score 1):

Has Haidro pointed out, Serebii has a guide to the Looker quest: http://www.serebii.net/xy/looker.shtml

If you're looking for the 5 notes:

> Magenta Plaza: In the Pokémon Center
>   Centrico Plaza: In the Gym
>   Vernal Avenue: In the herb shop
>   North Boulevard: In the hotel
>   North Boulevard: In the Museum

Note that just about any time during the Looker quests you can return to Looker's office (just off Rouge Plaza in one of the sidestreets) and talk to Looker to get the hints again, or use the Key Item Holocaster to review his latest message.